# Как можно "закодировать" изображения для python приложения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Я пишу python программу и собираю её pyinstaller'ом. Вся программная часть файлов собирается в exe, а прочие файлы (например, изображения) остаются доступными для пользователя. Как можно их "закодировать", например в dll, чтобы пользлователь не имел к ним доступа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я могу предложить довольно простой способ. Вы можете открыть файл, и переписать его в любой другой формат, отличающийся от формата вашей картинки. Вот пример моего кода.

```
img = open("111.jpg", "rb")
text = open("encode.ini", "wb")

text.write(img.read())

text.close()
img.close()
```

В итоге вы получите картинку в формате *.ini. Обычному пользователю будет не понятно, что хранится в данном файле, т.к. при открытии он обнаружит набор символов, а не картинку. Также если Вы боитесь, что все таки файл смогут "расшифровать", можно пройтись шифровкой, но это уже другая задача.

Чтобы получить картинку обратно, нужно переписать *.ini(в моем случае) в *.jpg(опять же в моем случае).

```
encode = open("encode.ini", "rb")
img = open("res.jpg", "wb")

img.write(encode.read())

img.close()
encode.close()
```

Comment: Просто "переписать" можно с успехом заменить на переименование с изменением расширения файла. Формат при этом, естественно, не меняется.